# Insert attribute into HTML elements with regex C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
string htmlHeaderPattern = ("(<h[2|3])>.*</h[2|3]>)");
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(mainBody, htmlHeaderPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

From this code, I get a bunch of h2 and h3-elements. In these, I'd like to insert an ID-attribute, with the value equal to (the content in the header, minus special chars and ToLower()). I also need this value as a separate string, as I need to store it for later use.

- Input: `<h3>Some sort of header!</h3>`
- Output: `<h3 id="#some-sort-of-header">Some sort of header!</h3>`
- Plus, I need the values "#some-sort-of-header" and "Some sort of header!" stored in a dictionary or list or whatever else.

This is what I have so far:

```
string htmlHeaderPattern = ("(<h[2|3]>.*</h[2|3]>)");
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(mainBody, htmlHeaderPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
Dictionary<string,string> returnValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (Match match in matches)
{

    string idValue = StripTextValue(match.Groups[4].Value);
     returnValue.Add(idValue, match.Groups[4].Value);
}
MainBody = Regex.Replace(mainBody, htmlHeaderPattern, "this is where i must replace all the headers with one with an ID-attribute?");
```

Any regex-wizards out there to help me?

Comment: Oh dear. Where did you get that regex? First, it's not a good idea to parse HTML with regex. Second, if you *have* to, at least use one that doesn't break if there are two headers on one line: `@"<h([23])>.*?</h\1>)"`

Comment: Is it just the `Regex.Replace` that you need help with?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: It's bloated with groups, I know. Sortof doing testing. Strip that away, and you'll get `<h[2|3]>.*</h[2|3]>`. And I know I shouldn't parse HTML with regex if I can avoid it, but I don't think I can in this case.

Comment: @Arve: Seeing as you're using C#, you could manipulate the HTML as an XML document instead.

Comment: @Arve: The groups aren't the problem. The regex will match more than one heading at once if they are on the same line, even from a `<h2>` to a `</h3>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of mentions regarding *not to use regex when parsing HTML*, so you could use e.g. [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) for this:

```
var html = @"<h2>Some sort of header!</h2>";

HtmlDocument document= new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

var headers = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2|//h3");
if (headers != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode header in headers)
    {
        var innerText = header.InnerText;
        var idValue = StripTextValue(innerText);
        if (header.Attributes["id"] != null)
        {
            header.Attributes["id"].Value = idValue;
        }
        else
        {
            header.Attributes.Add("id", idValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This code finds all the `<h2>` and `<h3>` elements in the document passed, gets inner text from there and setting(or adding) `id` attributes to them.

With this example you should get something like:

```
<h2 id='#some-sort-of-header'>Some sort of header!</h2>
```

Comment: Love it. Heard of the agilitypack before, but not used it. It's brilliant!

Comment: Not sure what StripTextValue is defined as